# How can I display success page, while running long PHP script in background that requires POST Data?

Tags: php, multithreading, preforking

I have a long running php script that requires $_POST data from the user. I would like the use to be able to submit the data and get a "Successfully started" page. However, after I show the user that page I still want to run a PHP script in the background that will take a while. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Forking, multiprocessing, calling external script? Keep in mind I need to submit the $_POST data to the long running script.

Comment: Have you considered using javascript and ajax?

Comment: You could queue the process in a DB table, and execute it via CRON. So user takes action, receives "*Successfully started*" page, *job* is inserted into *jobs* table, and CRON picks it up and runs it in the *background*. That's one way. You could also use `AJAX` to run the script in the background. User takes action, is immediately given "*Successfully started*" notice/feedback, and the script is now executing in the background/process. Even if the user navigates away from the page, the script/process will continue to run.

Comment: Can I pass the post variable through Ajax? I have used ajax through javascript but not through a PHP script. Would it look something like: 1. Page displays success, 2. Call ajax and pass post data to another php script, 3. Run external php script?